# AWS ALB not accepting keycloak token

Tags: amazon-web-services, keycloak, openid-connect

I am struggeling to get my keycloak working in the AWS with Application Load Balancer. The Application Load Balancer is configured with OIDC and a selfhosted and working keycloak. The configuration can be seen here:
[image]

The when opening the website of my application, I can see the keycloak login page and enter my credentials. Right after that, I get an 500 error. In the Logs of the Application Load Balancer I can see that the call is made, the certificate is valid but when the ALB is trying to query the user info endpoint, the Keycloak promts the following log:

```
[org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-17) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=35aa3ce3-c90a-47d7-9525-192a99ac45ca, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.31.28.209, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
```

What is the problem here? Why is the ALB not able to take the token which it requests successfully (I can see that in the logs) and provide it when calling the other endpoint? My Application is never called by the ALB. Can you please help me? Thanks.

Here is the response from the token endpoint from a rest client:
[image]

Here are the most important settings for my client in keycloak.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup. It might be due to wrong client credentials.

In keycloak, you only need `Client authentication` and `Standard flow`.
[Capability config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AKBL.png)

I suggest you leave Root URL and Home URL empty. Istead set "Valid redirect URIs" with the full FQDNs + URI path. e.g.

```
https://www.awesome.com/*
```

Then copy the credentials from the credentials tab:
[Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82yjR.png)

And finally, set the credentials in the load balancer rule:

[AWS Load Balancer rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENnGQ.png)

I hope this helps. Cheers!